# java Generic constructor undefined

Tags: java, generics

I am learning java and generics and stuck in some problem. I have read all the problems on generic posted on Stackoverflow but couldn't understand why this error occurs

```
class Student{

    String name;
    float marks;

    Student(String name,float marks){
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

}

public class GenericClassEx<T> {
    
    T obj;
        GenericClassEx(T data){
       
        this.obj = data;
    }

    public T getObject(){
        return this.obj;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Float d = new Float(10);
        GenericClassEx<Student> iobj= new GenericClassEx <Student> ("prince",d);
        System.out.println(iobj.getObject());
    }

}
```

when i run this code it says

```
GenericClassEx.java:28: error: constructor GenericClassEx in class GenericClassEx<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        GenericClassEx<Student> iobj= new GenericClassEx <Student> ("prince",d);
                                      ^
  required: Student
  found: String,Float
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class GenericClassEx
Note: GenericClassEx.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an object of `Student` to the constructor, `GenericClassEx(T data)`. Instead of that, you are passing two arguments, `"prince"` and `d` to it.

Replace

```
GenericClassEx<Student> iobj= new GenericClassEx <Student> ("prince",d);
```

with

```
GenericClassEx<Student> iobj = new GenericClassEx<Student>(new Student("prince", d));
```

As a side note, the constructor, [`Float​(double value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float-double-) is deprecated since Java-9.

Replace

```
Float d = new Float(10);
```

with

```
Float d = Float.valueOf(10);
```

Comment: but code i am learning from didnt use new and his code worked how?

Comment: @PrinceBhatia - The constructor, `GenericClassEx(T data)` expects just one object as the argument. Isn't it? And, you create an object of `Student` using `new Student("prince", d)`. Instead of a single statement, you can also do it with two statements as: `Student student = new Student("prince", d); GenericClassEx<Student> iobj = new GenericClassEx<Student>(student);`.

Comment: @PrinceBhatia the code you provided does evidently not work - wether or not you copied it incorrectly from the tutorial or the tutorial itself was buggy is a different topic, and an irrelevant one as well. This answer fixes your problem, end of story.